# Plotting dataframe using matplot lib

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

Hi I am trying to get a line plot for a dataframe:

i = [0.01,0.02,0.03,....,0.98,0.99,1.00]

values= [76,98,22,.....,32,98,100]

but there is index from 0,1,...99 as well and when I plot the index line also gets plotted. How do I ignore the plotting of index? I used the following code:

```
plt.plot(df,color= 'blue', label= 'values')
plt.title('values for corresponding i')
plt.legend(loc= 'upper right')
plt.xlabel("i")
plt.ylabel("values")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I fixed it by using xpoints= i, y points= values and did plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`plot.line`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.line.html) directly on pandas dataframe, it's a wrapper around matplotlib and it makes stuff easier.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate random DataFrame
i = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
values = np.random.randint(1, 100, 100)
df = pd.DataFrame({"i": i, "values": values})

# Plot
df.plot.line(x="i", y="values", color="blue", label="values")
plt.title("values for corresponding i")
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.xlabel("i")
plt.ylabel("values")
```

Result:

[image]